# How to make Google Sheet jump to today's column when opened?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I'm trying to adjust this code so that I can jump to today's date which are all across row 2 in my spreadsheet.

```
function onOpen() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange("A:A");
 var values = range.getValues();  
 var day = 24*3600*1000;  
 var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);  
 var ssdate; 
 for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
   try {
     ssdate = values[i][0].getTime()/day;
   }
   catch(e) {
   }
   if (ssdate && Math.floor(ssdate) == today) {
     sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(i,0,1,1));
     break;
   }    
 }
}
```

[this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/78927/how-to-make-google-sheet-jump-to-todays-row-when-opened) is from Marshmallow

I tried changing `sheet.getRange("A:A")` to `sheet.getRange("2:2")` and `sheet.getRange("C2:PB2")` but neither work.

Answer (score 5):

try this code:

```
function onOpen() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange("2:2");

 var values = range.getValues(); 
 values = values[0];
 var day = 24*3600*1000;  
 var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);  
 Logger.log(today);
 var ssdate; 
 for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
   try {
     ssdate = values[i].getTime()/day;
   }
   catch(e) {
   }
   if (ssdate && Math.floor(ssdate) == today) {
     sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(0,i,1,1));
     break;
   }    
 }

}
```

What was changed:

1. `sheet.getRange("2:2");` as you did
2. `values = values[0];` get the first row of data
3. `sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(0,i,1,1));` offset on columns

Comment: Thanks that works. The problem I now discover is it doesn't work in view only mode. I'm using my spreadsheet to show people's rotas, so ideally I'd like this to work in view only mode. 

i have a messy solution to that by giving editing rights to everyone then protecting the whole sheet with the exception of the date row, but it's not ideal.

Comment: @LondonRabbit onOpen trigger only runs for editors, not for viewers, actually viewers can't run scripts.

Answer (score 4):

If your dates are in column A, and you want your file to be opened on today's row:

1. In your google sheet: add this in the cell A1: `=match(TODAY();A2:A;0)+1`  It will return the row number which contains today's date (ex: row 154).
2. In script editor write this code that will automatically place your cursor on the cell A154:

```
    function onOpen() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var s = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // change to sheet containing dates
      var r = s.getRange("A1").getValue(); //change A1 to cell containing =match formula
      s.setActiveSelection(s.getRange("A" + r )); 
    }
```

This simple method avoids a lot of parsing and date conversions (All the glory to [GimelC](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/yb81IHfQsCg/ms605F72LtMJ))