# Google sheets: My timesheet is a pre-filled list of dates for the whole year How can I get quickly to today's date?

Tags: google-sheets

Or at least, to the last entry I made?

remember - i may enter my hours on last friday, but the sheet already has next monday's date pre-filled, so ctrl/end doesn't work.

the year goes to March 2017.

Answer (score 1):

#### Keyboard shortcut

Use Ctrl-Down to move to the last filled entry in the column with hours. More precisely, Ctrl-Down moves down to the next cell that either begins or ends a group of filled cells. If you do not have any blanks between filled-in cells, it goes to the last one. From there, pressing Down arrow again brings you to the cell waiting to be filled.

#### Script

A script can move the cursor to today's date when the spreadsheet is opened. See [How to make Google Sheet jump to today's row when opened?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/78996)