# How to make Google Sheets jump to closest date to today when opened?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, date, javascript

I have a Google sheet containing a list of events, with event dates listed in one column. I'd like to have my Google Sheets spreadsheet jump to the *closest* date to today's date on opening (i.e., either today or the next upcoming date).

Can someone help me with the script to do this?

I have tried using Script Editor to jump to the current date in my Google sheets spreadsheet ([using "function onOpen" solution posted previously](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/78996/196554)). However, since my date column does not include every day of the year (e.g., 09/25/18,  09/29/18, 09/30/18, 10/03/18 etc), the spreadsheet doesn't focus to the current period unless today's date happens to be one of those listed in my date column.

Comment: Checkout the solution shared on [this other answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/120275/88163). Does something like that works for you?

Comment: Thank you - but unfortunately, this won't work. The code you refer to depends on finding today's exact date in the date column. My date column skips many dates - so on some days the code would work (when that date happens to be in the date column), while on others it would fail due to that day's date not being listed. I need code that finds the closest date to today (=> today's date).

Comment: You could improve the formula on A1 (`=match(TODAY();A2:A;0)+1` ) to return `today or the next upcoming date` instead of `today()`

Comment: Can you give an example of code that would do this?

Comment: Take a look to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/121090/88163) which contains a couple of formulas that you could use instead of `=match(TODAY();A2:A;0)+1`

Comment: Thank you @Rubén - that displayd the closest date (as date value in cell containing the formula). However, the script I'm currently using, provided by you previously[1] looks for a row number value. So either the formula must return a row number to fit the script - or the script must be able to find the cell containing the matching date returned by the formula. Can you suggest a way to do that? [1]: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91944/how-to-make-google-sheet-jump-to-todays-column-when-opened/120275#120275

Answer (score 2):

I was able to piece together a solution thanks to the help of @Rubén who provided the elements. Perhaps there is a more elegant solution (with a single formula?), but this working for me.

This involves using formulas in 2 different cells, as well as a script.

1. Formula #1 (in cell A1 in this case) finds the closest date on or after today from the list of dates in column A.
2. Formula #2 (in cell B1 in this case) then returns the row number within column A that contains the date from cell A1.
3. Finally, the script (pasted into Tools>Script Editor) focuses the page upon loading to that row number.

### Formula #1 ##

*Placed in cell A1 in this case*

> ```
> =ArrayFormula(TO_DATE(MIN(if(A2:A>today(),A2:A))))
> ```
>
> //where A column contains dates. Looks for closest date on or after
>   today.

### Formula #2

*Placed in Cell B1, references Formula #1.*

> ```
> =match(A1,A2:A,0)+1
> ```
>
> "match ()" returns the row number, where A1 is the closest date on or
>   after today, and A column contains the list of dates.

### Script - in script editor:

*Focuses the sheet to the row indicated in formula 2 when the sheet is opened*

> ```
>  function onOpen() {
>   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
>   var s = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
>   var r = s.getRange("B1").getValue();
>   s.setActiveSelection(s.getRange("A" + r )); 
> }
> ```