# How to find the closest date to today from a list of dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I have a list of dates on column A. Each day I need to automatically put the date of today or the next closest date on cell B1.

```
20/8/2018
6/9/2018
25/9/2018
28/9/2018
11/10/2018
30/10/2018
31/10/2018
10/11/2018
15/11/2018
15/12/2018
```

I already tried using MATCH but it returns and index value. I could use INDEX to get the date corresponding to that index value.

`=INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(TODAY(),A1:A10,1)+1)`

Is there a simpler/ straight forward way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method to get the same result is, but I don't think that it could be simpler or straight forward but maybe it could me "more logical" for a "non spreadsheet thinker"

`=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(A1:A10,A1:A10>=TODAY()),1,1)`

- FILTER returns an array of values that that met the condition.
- ARRAY_CONSTRAIN reduce the size of the array, in this case, returns a single value. The same could be achieved by using INDEX.